# How to enumerate all users from global catalog?

Tags: visual-c++, active-directory, com

I am using [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/netds/adsi/activedir/gcallusers/vc/gcallusers.cpp) to enumerate users from global catalog.
This code working fine if we run it on windows server.

To connect global catalog from another machine I have modified below code snippet.

```
hr = ADsOpenObject(L"GC://serverip",
    L"domain\\username",
    L"password",
    ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION,
    IID_IADsContainer,
    (void**)&pContainer);
```

After above change my code is failing at below line.

```
hr = pEnum->Next(1, &var, &lFetch);
```

I googled it but not found appropriate solution.
What I am missing here?
My requirement is to get all users from global catalog from remote windows server.

Comment: What error are you getting? hr value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research I found that Active directory server and my client machine was not in same domain.
After changing domain name of my client machine after code snippet is working fine.